# How to sanitize a $_GET on Typo3 extension?

Tags: typo3, extbase

I have an extension that access a file directory. I use an ajax function to send the path that needs to be access to the controller and in the controller I use a $_GET cause I haven't figure it out how to make it work otherwise.

```
$image_file_path = $_GET["url_region"];
$d = dir($image_file_path) or die("File not found!");
```

But of course when you request for something else like ../../.. you can access all other directories.

Could you suggest me a way to sanitize this? Please!

Comment: You can be very strict with what an allowed path is and check whether the user-supplied value matches but it will always be prone to some mis-validation. It's easier to simply check that the URL was created by your extension. That's done by having some secret key in the URL that nobody can guess and that you can use to validate that all the parameters are genuinely from your extension. That's what the `cHash` method suggested by **cweiske** does so my +1 for his answer.

Comment: @cascaval, thank you for explaning. I will research on that option :)

Answer (score 1):

You should provide a `cHash` as URL parameter and let TYPO3 verify that. This way you can be sure the URL has been generated by TYPO3 itself and thus is valid.

Comment: Maybe you can extend your answer by giving some practical code examples.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using  `t3lib_div::_GET()` which unescapes the parameters regardless what php.ini magic_quotes says.

Comment: Might want to point out the security ramifications: You are using a GET parameter to get the file path and it will be accessed in some way further down the line. Now, how can this be misused? Apart from that, this answer is really outdated nowadays (t3lib_div).

Answer (score 0):

You easily could use a regex to catch all "../" - values of the parameter. The other way could be, that the available paths being defined in a array, or something else, to check up the right access.